# Are the following php functions enough to protect against hackers in my chatbox application?

Tags: php, function, security

I mainly want to prevent hacks that can be written via scripts through the send message and chose username fields.

```
function protect($v) {
    $v = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
    $v = htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES);
    $v = stripslashes($v);
    $v = trim($v);

    return $v;
}
```

Are the above php functions enough? I don't need something super high security, just enough to have done all the basics right.

Comment: The functions are called in exactly the wrong order. -- I wonder where that originated, I've seen that a couple of times already.

Comment: It's not secure enough!  Run more functions!  `Which functions sir?`  ALL OF THEM.

Comment: @Frank Farmer That would be crazy. A basic XSS / MySQL injection prevention just needs mysql_real_escape_string & htmlentities.

Comment: @thew Tongue planted firmly in cheek ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For basic security:

mysql_real_escape_string EVERYTHING when you do a SQL Query, htmlentities when you want to echo something from the database.

Example:

```
<?php
    $sql = " 
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            table
        WHERE
            id = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) ."'
        LIMIT 1
    ";           // above this is the first security

    $mysql = mysql_query($sql);

    if($mysql){
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql);

        echo htmlentities($result); // And here the second
    } 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the more practical way of adding in security, i was just copying and pasting mostly from a tutorial

Comment: A couple years later though, but still of notice: `htmlspecialchars` escapes enough characters to make your application safe. `htmlentities` escapes a bit too much wich wouldn't hurt if you would escape short amounts of text but with larger amounts it can hurt your loading times.

Answer (score 0):

start using PDO. It will save you from headaches like these.